# Fibonacci die probability

Tags: probability

I was doing an exam review and I have absolutely no idea how to do this question. There is no solution to this so I'm hoping someone here knows how to do this.

The fibonacci numbers are defined as follows: f<sub>0</sub>=0, f<sub>1</sub>=1, and f<sub>n</sub>=f<sub>n-1</sub> + f<sub>n-2</sub> for n>=2.
Let n be a large integer. A fibonacci die is a die that has f<sub>n</sub> faces. Such a die is fair: If we roll it, each face is on top with the same probability 1/f<sub>n</sub>. There are three different types of fibonacci dice.

- D1: f<sub>n-2</sub> of its faces show the number 1 and the other f<sub>n-1</sub> faces show the number 4.
- D2: Each face shows the number 3
- D3: f<sub>n-2</sub> of its faces show the number 5 and the other f<sub>n-1</sub> faces show the number 2.

Assume we roll each of D1, D2, and D3 once, independently of each other. Let R<sub>1</sub>, R<sub>2</sub>, and R<sub>3</sub> be the numbers on the top face of D1, D2, and D3, respectively. Determine Pr(R<sub>1</sub> > R<sub>2</sub>) and Pr(R<sub>2</sub> > R<sub>3</sub>) and show that Pr(R<sub>3</sub> > R<sub>1</sub>) = ((f<sub>n-1</sub>)(f<sub>n+1</sub>)) / (f<sub>n</sub>)<sup>2</sup>

Comment: Would you please check that you copied the subscripts correctly on the last line of your question?

Comment: Please watch capitalization.  $n \neq N$ in your fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Pr(R_1 > R_2)$ is just the probability that $R_1 = 4$, which is $\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}$. Similarly, $Pr(R_2 > R_3) = \frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}$. For $Pr(R_3 > R_1)$ we have

$$\frac{f_{n-2}f_n + f_{n-1}f_{n-2}}{(f_n)^2} = \frac{f_{n-2}(f_n + f_{n-1})}{(f_n)^2} = \frac{f_{n-2}f_{n+1}}{(f_n)^2}.$$

Possibly a typo in your question, or I've made a small mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  D2 beats D1 $\frac {f_{n-2}}{f_n}$ of the time because it beats the $1$'s and loses to the $4$'s.  What about D3 vs D2?  There are four possibilities when you compare D1 and D3.  The fraction should remind you of a Fibonacci identity. The last $f_1$ looks like it should be $f_n$

Comment: You're right. It was a typo.